# Size of hash value when using hash join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, hashtable

I have a question regarding the usage of hash join in SQL Server.
As I understand it, the mechanism of hash join involves hashing the keys of one table and storing them in hash buckets (referred to as the build phase). Then, the keys of the other table are also hashed, and the matching data is compared with the data in the buckets to produce the join results (referred to as the probe phase).

I'm curious about the hashing algorithm used in SQL Server when hashing the keys, specifically whether it uses one of the listed algorithms such as SHA2_256 or SHA2_512. Additionally, I would like to know the size of the hashed key in terms of the number of bytes.

In SQL Server, the provided hash function is as follows:

```
HASHBYTES ( '<algorithm>', { @input | 'input' } )
<algorithm>::= MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512
```

I'm wondering if one of these algorithms is used to hash the keys for a hash join or if a different algorithm is used.

I searched the official docs but couldn't find any specific information about that.

Comment: It's not documented. The article here indicates that it is 32 bits at least some of the time https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/07/join-performance-implicit-conversions-and-residuals.html (and is a "perfect hash" for integer not null)

Comment: I doubt it's any of the hashbytes algos, those are hashes with different properties, designed to make reverse computation harder, not to provide good distribution and speed of calculation which is something that joined hash might need

Comment: @MartinSmith So, if I understand correctly, the minimum size of the hashed key value is 32 bits (4 bytes), is that right?
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I don't know. TBH I assume so because I'm not sure there would be any use cases for needing any more buckets than 4,294,967,296. Maybe there are some people out there doing hash joins with billions of distinct join keys though 

Comment: The article was written in 2011 - there may have been changes since then. It doesn't explicitly say that 32 bits was the only size then but these days it would at least be viable on many installs to have hash tables held entirely in memory with a greater amount of buckets if needed.

Comment: @MartinSmith
Thank you for your kind comments. Thanks to you, I was able to gain a deeper understanding of hash algorithms in SQL Server.